# Print memory address for Ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays, pointers, memory

```
irb> class A; end
=> nil
irb> a=A.new
=> "#<A:0x3094638>"
irb> a.inspect
=> "#<A:0x3094638>"
irb> b=[]
=> []
irb> b.inspect
=> "[]"
```

How to get memory address of an array object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the method [`Object#object_id`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-object_id).

> Returns an integer identifier for *obj*. The same number will be returned on all calls to id for a given object, and no two active objects will share an id. `#object_id` is a different concept from the `:name` notation, which returns the symbol id of name.

Example :-

```
Arup-iMac:arup_ruby $ irb
2.1.2 :001 > s = "I am a string"
 => "I am a string" 
2.1.2 :002 > obj_id = s.object_id
 => 2156122060 
2.1.2 :003 > ObjectSpace._id2ref obj_id
 => "I am a string" 
2.1.2 :004 >
```

Comment: If `object_id` differ could I say for sure that there are two different objects? And if these ids are the same is this the same object?

Comment: @Paul Yes.. You should.

Comment: Not necessarily a memory address, though. In particular, it won't be a memory address for `3`, `:foo`, `nil`, `false`... (although it still will be unique). But for most objects, it will be a pointer, at least on MRI. Fun fact: for small integers `n`, `object_id` should be `n * 2 + 1`. `-1.object_id == -1`! :)

Comment: @Amadan Humm.. True...True. `object_id` is enough to get the `object` address and the same address can be used to get the object back. :-)

Comment: I have `@channels` array in a class. The class should be instantiated once, but when I call the instance from one thread `@channels.length` is 1 and from other thread = 0. `object_id` is the same. Array is created and filled only during object's initialization. What could go on?

Comment: What kind of *objects* `@channels` contains ?